# Transition of images in Windows Forms Picture box

Tags: windows, winforms

I'm new to Windows Forms, in my project, i need to change the image in the picture box at runtime. I'm able to do that with the help of a timer. The picture just gets changed. Is it possible to do some transitions when image changes, for example fade in, fade out, blur etc.. If possible could some one please let me know how to do it. I searched in net but in vain.Thanks in advance.

Varun

Answer (score 4):

Simply take new code file and paste below code in it

an original answer for the similar question, answer taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519956/drawimage-with-opacity/5520096#5520096)

### Answer

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class BlendPanel : Panel
{
private Image mImg1;
private Image mImg2;
private float mBlend;
public BlendPanel()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
}
public Image Image1
{
    get { return mImg1; }
    set { mImg1 = value; Invalidate(); }
}
public Image Image2
{
    get { return mImg2; }
    set { mImg2 = value; Invalidate(); }
}
public float Blend
{
    get { return mBlend; }
    set { mBlend = value; Invalidate(); }
}
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (mImg1 == null || mImg2 == null)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    else
    {
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
        cm.Matrix33 = mBlend;
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImg2, rc, 0, 0, mImg2.Width, mImg2.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
        cm.Matrix33 = 1F - mBlend;
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImg1, rc, 0, 0, mImg1.Width, mImg1.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
}
```

Build your project.  You can now drop a BlendPanel from the top of the toolbox onto your form.  Here's a sample program that uses it:

```
    private float mBlend;
    private int mDir = 1;
    public int count = 0;
    public Bitmap[] pictures;

    public void myPhoto()
    {
        pictures = new Bitmap[9];
        pictures[0] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\cf3.jpg");
        pictures[1] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\cf4.jpg");
        pictures[2] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l1.JPG");
        pictures[3] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l2.JPG");
        pictures[4] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l3.JPG");
        pictures[5] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l4.JPG");
        pictures[6] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l5.JPG");
        pictures[7] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l6.JPG");
        pictures[8] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l7.JPG");

        timer1.Interval = 50; //time of transition
        timer1.Tick += BlendTick;
        try
        {
            blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
            blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void BlendTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mBlend += mDir * 0.02F;
        if (mBlend > 1)
        {
            mBlend = 0.0F;
            if ((count + 1) < pictures.Length)
            {
                blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
            }
            else
            {
                blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[0];
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        blendPanel1.Blend = mBlend;
    }
```

You'll need to modify the `new Bitmap(@"yourimagePath");` calls.  Build and run.  You should see the displayed image smoothly morph from your first image to your second image without any flickering.

I hope it helps for other...

Comment: Plagiarized from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520096/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant I wanted to reference your answer but didn't find at that time, I just wanted to add only second part of my answer. anyway I added your answer as a reference

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for such effects, but you can implement them. I'd suggest to write a custom control that renders the image and have a method for fade-swap, fade itself can be reached with [alpha-blending](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB10102005010514AM/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB.aspx) drawing with .NET Graphics class.

However, Graphics class isn't very fast, I don't recommend to use this technique for big images. If you need some fancy UI with hw-accelerated effects, take a look at WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Blend effects are easy to get going by using the ColorMatrix class.  There's a good example available in my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2b4c5c41-8f3c-4e81-9169-78082b80c747/).

A simple way to get a blur is to resize the image, making it smaller, then redraw it back, making it larger.  The Graphics.InterpolationMode property affects the type of blur you'll get.

Those are quicky do-it-yourself solutions.  Any decent graphics library has these kind of operations built-in.  You probably want something free, check out ImageMagick.NET

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, not without external (3rd-party) libraries.