# How to merge 2 images in Grid ? WPF

Tags: c#, kinect

I have 1 image which contains the camera view and 1 image which contains the skeleton tracking .
But i could not merge them together , any idea how to do it so that the skeleton tracking will be with the camera view

Comment: I don't think that it matters that you are using WPF or a `Grid` panel. You'll want to transform the two images into a single image before applying that image to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this should work:

[Merging two images in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465172/merging-two-images-in-c-net)

The general algorithm is:

1. Create a new bitmap
2. Get the 'graphics plane' of that bitmap.
3. Draw the two bitmaps you want onto that plane.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to blend the two images together so that the skeleton is "overlaid" onto the background? If so, then here is previous answer (that I wrote) which contains [3 alternative approaches with source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170894/drawing-image-with-additive-blending/12210258#12210258).

These are a per-pixel approach (which may be overkill for what you are doing but you will have full control of how the images are combined). You will need to be careful to handle transparency correctly.