# How to create fade button effect with pictureboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, graphics, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create an effect so when the user hovers the mouse over a picturebox, the button fades to a `hoverimage`, and when they leave, it fades back to the original. I'm using pictureboxes as buttons in a program.  I'm doing this because all the buttons will be pictures with no button textures, so I didn't see the point in using a button. Just so you can visualize it, here is the original image:

[image]

And the image to fade to:

[image]

I could still change these images a bit, but thats the general idea.

How would I go about creating this fading effect? I'm picturing something using timers and opacity settings, but I don't know how any of that stuff could help me solve this.

E: Heres a bit of code I have. It changes from image to image when I hover, but its not a fade, and it looks very choppy.

```
    private void pictureBox3_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox3.Image = pictureBox37.Image;
    }

    private void pictureBox3_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox3.Image = pictureBox38.Image;
    }
```

`pictureBox37 and pictureBox38` are invisible reference pictureboxes with the images I need.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2b4c5c41-8f3c-4e81-9169-78082b80c747/gdic-transition-between-two-images?forum=winforms

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any WinForms support for this kind of animation, so you'd have to do this manually.  If you have more than one of these buttons, I recommend creating your own UserControl with this functionality.  I can give you some pointers how to do this:

- Your UserControl will have two Image properties, one for the normal and one for the hover image
- You'll have to override the OnPaint method to do your own custom painting, blending these two images onto your Graphics according to a `position` property.  This is a float where 0 indicates showing the normal image and 1 the hover image.  Any value in between means a blend of these two images.  I found some good blending code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519956/drawimage-with-opacity).
- Then you'll need a Timer to update this position dynamically and redraw the button (by calling Invalidate). I recommend using a Windows.Forms.Timer, which has the advantage that its Tick event is always executed on the main Thread, so you don't have to use Invoke to modify your control.
- And last but not least you override the OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave methods, to set this all into motion.  These methods could set a `positionChange` property that indicates in which direction `position` is changing.

Hope this helps ...