# How to fade in and fade out (Fading transition ) image on panel(backgroud image)?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm sending to my method different images and I want insert some effect to this change.

How can I fade in and fade out images?

```
 private void ShowImage(Image image, ImageLayout imageLayout, int numberOfSeconds)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.image_timer != null)
                this.KillImageTimer();

            this.customer_form.DisplayImage(image, imageLayout);

            this.image_timer = new Timer();
            this.image_timer.Tick += (object s, EventArgs a) => NextImage();
            this.image_timer.Interval = numberOfSeconds* 1000;
            this.image_timer.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Do nothing
        }


public void DisplayImage(Image image, ImageLayout imageLayout)
    {
        panel1.BackgroundImage = image;
        panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = imageLayout;
    }
```

Comment: Is this Winforms? Or ASP or WPF? Or what?? - And: What is numberOfSeconds supposed to mean: The time of the fade-in or out or the time between??

Comment: It's winform and numberOfSecond is time for how long image will be background image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520096/17034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built-in fading transitions in `Winforms`.

So you will need to write one yourself.

The simplest one I can think of uses a second `Panel`, that is layered upon the first one and in fact needs to be **inside** the first `Panel` or else the transparency effect won't work..

Here is the setup, using two `Panels`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    pan_image.BackgroundImage = someImage;

    pan_layer.Parent = pan_image;
    pan_layer.BackColor = pan_image.BackColor;
    pan_layer.Size = pan_image.Size;
    pan_layer.Location = Point.Empty;
}
```

For the fading animation I use a `Timer`. This is a quick code example:

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
int counter = 0;
int dir = 1;               // direction 1 = fade-in..
int secondsToWait = 5;
int speed1 = 25;           // tick speed ms
int speed2 = 4;            // alpha (0-255) change speed

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // we have just waited and now we fade-out:
    if (dir == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop(); 
        dir = -speed2;
        counter = 254;
        timer1.Interval = speed2;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    // the next alpha value:
    int alpha =  Math.Min(Math.Max(0, counter+= dir), 255);

    button1.Text = dir > 0 ? "Fade In" : "Fade Out";

    // fully faded-in: set up the long wait:
    if (counter >= 255)
    { 
        timer1.Stop(); 
        button1.Text = "Wait";
        timer1.Interval = secondsToWait * 1000;
        dir = 0;
        timer1.Start();


    }
    // fully faded-out: try to load a new image and set direction to fade-in or stop
    else if (counter <= 0)
    {
        if ( !changeImage() ) 
           {
             timer1.Stop(); 
             button1.Text = "Done";
           }
        dir = speed2;
    }

    // create the new, semi-transparent color:
    Color col = Color.FromArgb(255 - alpha, pan_image.BackColor);
    // display the layer:
    pan_layer.BackColor = col;
    pan_layer.Refresh();

}
```

I start it in a Button, on which I also show the current state:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dir = speed2;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    timer1.Interval = speed1;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

As you can see I use two speeds you can set: One to control the speed of the `Timer` and one to control the steps by which the transparency changes on each `Tick`.

The effect is created by simply changing the `Color` from the `BackgroundColor` of the image `Panel` to fully transparent and back, waiting in between for a specified number of seconds.

And the end of the effect I call a function  `changeImage()` to change the images. If this function returns `false` the `Timer` is stopped for good..

I'm pretty sure this could be written in a cleaner and more elegant way, but as it is it seems to work..

**Update**

- for flicker-free display use a double-buffered control, like this Panel subclass:

---

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{
    public DrawPanel()      { DoubleBuffered = true;  }
}
```

Here is a sample implementation for `changeImage`:

```
bool changeImage()
{
    if (pan_image.BackgroundImage != null)
    {
        var img = pan_image.BackgroundImage;
        pan_image.BackgroundImage = null;
        img.Dispose();
    }
    pan_image.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imageFiles[index++]);
    return index < imageFiles.Count;
}
```

It assumes two class level variables: a `List<string> imageFiles` filled with file names of images for a slide-show and an `int index = 0`.

Comment: where is changeImage() routine code? just tell me what changeImage function suppose to do.......plzz

Comment: Good catch. The function was described but not with its name in the answer.. I have updated the answer.

Comment: still changeImage body not found. can u plzz post the full code if possible.

Comment: The code is up to you! The post is about fade-in-out in a slide-show. So you write a function that changes the image to another one until you are done; return true unless you are done. Here is an example `bool changeImage()
        {
            pan_image.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imageFiles[++index]);
            return index < imageFiles.Count;
        }` . It assumes a `List<string> imageFiles` with image file names.

Comment: when you gave the code then it would be better if you post complete code so any one can understand. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I guess you are right; even I couldn't quite get it after two years. but otoh all those upvoters did.. ;-) - See the update!

Comment: i try to work with you code but unfortunate i could not get it done. so can u plzz look at my code which i post in msdn forum here is the url https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8957c379-3975-448a-9e5c-a54831da1e87/code-issue-for-image-transition-with-effect?forum=winforms

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do your debugging. I have pasted my code to a new project and it did work. Note that you need to load some inages and also decide on the size of the pbox. What does not work? You need to be much more specific when describing your problems!

Comment: you said "I have pasted my code to a new project and it did work" so would you share your project code. please upload your project code to onedrive or github.

Comment: `pan_image and pan_layer` which one should be on top of which control? both will have same size and same location ?

Comment: Pan_image must be placed and sized right (ie as you wish). The other will place and size itself. note that the sizing must be repeated when you resize pan_image. This is all in the first 5 ines of the above code!

Comment: Can you access [this](https://sabercathost.com/d5KM/slideshowform.zip) ?

Comment: the reason is not clear to me that why you take two panel ?