# Fade effects in Windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add somefading effects to a button, a picturebox and a text box, using Windows Forms.

I know I should use WPF for this, but I never worked with it and it's to complicated for me and my project is to advanced to switch platforms now.

I have this, but the opacity/fading effect isn't smooth at all.

```
public void Animation(Button button1) {
    var expandTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    var contractTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    expandTimer.Interval = 10;
    contractTimer.Interval = 10;
    DateTime animationStarted = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan animationDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
    int initialWidth = 75;
    int endWidth = 130;

    button1.MouseHover += (_, args) => {
        contractTimer.Stop();
        expandTimer.Start();
        animationStarted = DateTime.Now;
        button1.ForeColor = Color.DimGray;
    };

    button1.MouseLeave += (_, args) => {
        expandTimer.Stop();
        contractTimer.Start();
        animationStarted = DateTime.Now;
        button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    };

    expandTimer.Tick += (_, args) => {
        double percentComplete = (DateTime.Now - animationStarted).Ticks
                / (double)animationDuration.Ticks;
        button1.Visible = false;

        if (percentComplete >= 1) {
            expandTimer.Stop();

        } else {
            button1.Width = (int)(initialWidth +
                    (endWidth - initialWidth) * percentComplete);

        }
    };

    contractTimer.Tick += (_, args) => {
        double percentComplete = (DateTime.Now - animationStarted).Ticks
                / (double)animationDuration.Ticks;
        button1.Visible = true;

        if (percentComplete >= 1) {
            contractTimer.Stop();

        } else {
            button1.Width = (int)(endWidth -
                    (endWidth - initialWidth) * percentComplete);
        }
    };
}
```

How can I fix the not so smooth transitions without having to switch to WPF?

Comment: Do you have a mockup of what it should look like? Post that. Also try to post an active snippet showing the result of your current code. (IDK if you can do that with Visual Studio code)

Comment: Start with the basics:  is your Form `DoubleBuffered`?

Comment: @HunterStevens yeah check out this video,at 7:00,that's how the effects should look.

Comment: Timer resolution is larger than 10ms, so this is one source of jumpiness. (Set it to 25!)  - You may want to have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563782/how-to-fade-in-and-fade-out-fading-transition-image-on-panelbackgroud-image/28565675?s=1|1.7543#28565675) for a fasing effect with transparency.. - But really smooth animation will not happen in winForms anyway, alas, as it can't synch with the monitor :-(

Comment: So, how is a single line of XAML much more "complicated" than the horrendous useless hacks you're trying to do here? `<DoubleAnimation TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" to="0" Duration="00:00:00.5"/>`

Comment: Well. I found it complicated to work in WPF to be honest. 1. I don't know how to add a background into my form.

Comment: @BogdanMocanu `Well. I found it complicated to work in WPF` - The fact that you *don't know* how to do stuff  doesn't mean it's "complicated" at all. In fact, winforms is much more "complicated" than WPF because it doesn't support  anything and  is completely useless. `<Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/tunero_430_03.jpg"/>
    </Window.Background>`, loads an image directly  from the internet without writing  any code whatsoever. Of course you can also use local images or project  resources. If you want a rich UI, forget winforms.

Comment: I'll try switching to WPF once again.I guess I am to old allready :)))

Comment: WPF is extremely complicated compared to WinForms. However, for visual effects (if it really matters) and while staying in desktop apps, it is probably your best bet. This or directx for more control. Alternatively, you can look into custom/3rd party controls that provide support for themes - perhaps you can design it such as no coding is necessary. Or switch to web - there you get tremendous support with tons of code already written for you. It's also an order of magnitude more simple than WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying, you may not even care anymore about getting an answer as this question is almost 1 year old. I felt the need to post this answer because I think it does help answer the OP's question, and not by providing a solution but by providing a road-map of how to get to the solution...I think that's the best way to learn.

Let's begin...

Transitions are choppy because your event handler for "MouseHover" fires continuously as the mouse hovers over the control. This is causing your animations to get interrupted and making them appear choppy.

My recommendation here, use the "MouseEnter" event to start your timer.

Investigate a little more and you might find similarities between your two timers and use a single timer to do both tasks by creating your own timer that has a method that can be triggered by these two events to cause the button to grow or shrink.

Also, though people have suggested WPF (and I don't disagree, WPF can be useful), don't lose faith in System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score -1):

Although this might be easier supported in WPF here is solution that works in WinForms.

When I need to animate I find it much easier to have ONE single background thread that coordinates the animation over an instance that keeps track of the progress. Having an Animation class instance that simple gets called frequently on a background worker makes the headache a lot less.

#### AnimateButton

Lets first look at how we can animate a button. For internal housekeeping and keeping track of for which buttons we already have an animation going we use the static method `Animate`. It takes a button and a direction as parameter and then finds or updates the instance that belongs to the button.

The key feature is the [`Execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.icommandexecutor.execute(v=vs.110).aspx) method that is an implementation of the interface `ICommandExecutor`. That method gets called every time the next step of an animation is needed (it gets called with a rate of 30 fps). In this case I only change the Width based on the direction but if needed more properties can be changed. Don't loop or block this method though because `Excecute` will run on the UI thread and that thread doesn't like to be held up to much.

```
    // resize a button
    private class AnimateButton : ICommandExecutor
    {
        // keep track of instances of this class
        static ConcurrentDictionary<Button, AnimateButton> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<Button, AnimateButton>();

        // Update or create an animation for a button
        static public void Animate(Button sender, Direction direction)
        {
            AnimateButton animate;
            // find it...
            if (dict.TryGetValue(sender, out animate))
            {
                animate.SetDirection(direction);
            }
            else
            {
                // create a new one
                animate = new AnimateButton(sender);
                animate.SetDirection(direction);
                if (dict.TryAdd(sender, animate))
                {
                    Animations.List.Add(animate);
                } 
                else
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("button not added ?!?");
                }
            }
        }

        int initialWidth = 75;
        int endWidth = 130;

        public enum Direction
        {
            None,
            Shrink,
            Grow
        }

        Direction direction = Direction.None;
        readonly Button button;

        private AnimateButton(Button button)
        {
            this.button = button;
        }

        public void SetDirection(Direction direction )
        {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        // this gets called by the progress event
        public void Execute()
        {
            switch(direction)
            {
                case Direction.Grow:
                    if (button.Width < endWidth)
                    {
                        button.Width++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        direction =  Direction.None;
                    }
                    break;
                case Direction.Shrink:
                    if (button.Width > initialWidth)
                    {
                        button.Width--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        direction = Direction.None;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### ActiveAnimations

On the form their needs to be a masterlist of animations that need to be processed. The class `ActiveAnimations` does that. It holds a `ConcurrentBag` of `ICommandExcutor` instances.

```
    // for multiple animations
    private class Animations
    {
        // both the UI thread and backgroud thread will use this
        static  ConcurrentBag<ICommandExecutor> activeAnimations = new ConcurrentBag<ICommandExecutor>();

        public static ConcurrentBag<ICommandExecutor> List
        {
            get
            {
                return activeAnimations;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Timer

To drive the animations forward a [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is used. I prefer that one because it comes with the capability to switch to the UI thread without the need of extra lines of code. The timer Interval is set to 30 milliseconds.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // loop over all active animations and have them execute one step
    foreach (var command in Animations.List)
    {
        command.Execute();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to start the timer in the `Form_Load` event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

#### The hover and leave events

As we have the plumbing in place we can now create the `AnimateButton` instances in the events on the buttons:

```
    private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnimateButton.Animate((Button)sender, AnimateButton.Direction.Grow);
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnimateButton.Animate((Button)sender, AnimateButton.Direction.Shrink);
    }
```

You can have multiple buttons animating. I tested it with 2 buttons and that worked well. You can always consider reducing the fps by increasing the Interval of the timer.

If all is implemented correctly this will be your result:

[image: animating buttons in action]