# Moving a picture box gradually, not instantly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an PictureBox that I want to move up on the y axis after a button click. The problem is that the PictureBox simply appears there after the button click. I want it to move to the new position, not teleport. What do I do?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Point stageplus1 = new Point(164, 325);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox5.Location = stageplus1;
    }

    private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: WinForms won't do a "slide" movement like you're wanting.  You'll need to move the object by using a `Timer` to move the box gradually.  Clicking the button enables the timer.  Each time the timer fires, move the box up a small amount; once the box is in the desired location, turn the timer back off.

Comment: @BJMyers Not necessarily true. See [AnimateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @LarsTech Is that actually WinForms though?  It's an API provided by Windows that you could conceivably use from WinForms, but I wouldn't consider it part of the WinForms API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [BJ Myers comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298057/moving-a-picture-box-gradually-not-instantly#comment56338106_34298057) this is how you can implement that:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    // calculate new position
    this.pictureBox1.Top++;
    this.pictureBox1.Left++;

    // when to stop
    if (this.pictureBox1.Top > (this.Height - (2 * this.pictureBox1.Height)))
    {
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I used the default [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) control that raises a Tick at an interval. The Tick event gets executed on the UI thread so you don't have to be bothered by cross thread errors.

If added to your form this is what you'll get:

[image: Kenny moves]

If you need to animate more stuff you might want to look into using a Background worker and helper classes like I show in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595983/fade-effects-in-windows-forms/31627394#31627394)