# Simple animation in Windows Form Applications

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, bitmap

I want to make simple animation in my Windows Form application. I have some bitmap objects and I want them to show in random places. For example, moving from bottom to the top. How can I do this?

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595983/fade-effects-in-windows-forms/31627394#31627394) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298057/moving-a-picture-box-gradually-not-instantly/34566523#34566523)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some image i.e. in `PictureBox` and...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int MinX = 0;
    private const int MaxX = 150;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Run "animation" in separate thread to avoid UI blocking
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int x = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                if (x > MaxX)
                    x = MinX;
                x += 1;

                // Change must be delegated to the UI thread
                pictureBox.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    pictureBox.Location = new Point(x, pictureBox.Location.Y);
                }));
                Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Got the idea?