# How to use a timer to change the contents of a picture box every 3 seconds

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make a fancy home screen which alternates between three pictures, every 3 seconds. How will i do this and, if possible, is it possible to make them fade in and out to look a bit better?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub frmLoadUp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim images As New List(Of Image)()
    images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\home pc.png"))
    images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\mid range pc.png"))
    images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\high end pc.png"))

    Dim pictureChangeTimer As New Timer()
    AddHandler pictureChangeTimer.Tick, AddressOf pictureChangeTimer_tick
    pictureChangeTimer.Interval = 3000
    pictureChangeTimer.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub pictureChangeTimer_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Index = (Index + 1) Mod images.Count()
    PictureBox1.Image = images(Index)
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\home pc.png")
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\mid range pc.png")
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\high end pc.png")

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably easier to just make an animated gif.

Comment: @braX I am using vb.net. I have included my current code in the edited question.

Comment: @LukeCassidy If your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

You need a few changes:

(1) Declare Images at the class level
(2) Change your picture timer to set the image by index and reset the index

```
Dim Images As New List(Of Image)()
Dim Index as Integer

Private Sub frmLoadUp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
    Images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\home pc.png"))
    Images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\mid range pc.png"))
    Images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\high end pc.png"))
    Index = -1;
    Dim pictureChangeTimer As New Timer()
    AddHandler pictureChangeTimer.Tick, AddressOf pictureChangeTimer_tick
    pictureChangeTimer.Interval = 3000
    pictureChangeTimer.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub pictureChangeTimer_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Index = If(Index = 2, 0, Index + 1)

    PictureBox1.Image = Images(Index)  

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, on the "If(Index = 2, 0, Index + 1)" line, it says "Value of type (boolean, integer, integer) cannot be converted to boolean. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I don't think your code will compile. Also, what have you got against the image at index 2?

Comment: Maybe you mean: `Index = If(Index = 2, 0, Index + 1)`

Comment: @Mary There are three images (0, 1, 2) if index = 2 the index should be reset to zero

Comment: @LukeCassidy - sorry I had a slight bug and have updated the answer

Comment: Now that you corrected you "slight bug" it will compile and work. I wouldn't call an inability to compile a "slight bug". If you have not quite arrived to write code off the top of your head, you should test it. My biggest one is forgetting to open a connection and I don't test with a database I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Fill your list in the Form.Load but makes the list a Form level (class level) variable so you can see it from any method in the form. You can add the Timer in the designer and set its properties there. The image will start out at index 0; Integer initializes to zero.

When your timer ticks we increment Index (which is also a Form level variable; it will hold its value between calls to the method). Next we check if we have come to the end of the list and reset to zero if we have.

```
Private Index As Integer
Private images As New List(Of Image)()

Private Sub frmLoadUp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\home pc.png"))
    images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\mid range pc.png"))
    images.Add(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\lukem\Desktop\TO COPY TO ONEDRIVE\PCs\high end pc.png"))

    Dim pictureChangeTimer As New Timer()
    AddHandler pictureChangeTimer.Tick, AddressOf pictureChangeTimer_tick
    pictureChangeTimer.Interval = 3000
    PictureBox1.Image = images(Index)
    pictureChangeTimer.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub pictureChangeTimer_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Index += 1
    If Index > 2 Then 'There is no Index 3 so we start from the beginning again
        Index = 0
    End If
    PictureBox1.Image = Images(Index)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to blend images.

First of all, create custom picture box.(code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5520096/12666543))

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class CustomPictureBox
Inherits PictureBox

Private mImg1 As Image
Private mImg2 As Image
Private mBlend As Single
Public Sub New()
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True)
End Sub
Public Property Image1 As Image
    Get
        Return mImg1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        mImg1 = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Image2 As Image
    Get
        Return mImg2
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        mImg2 = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Blend As Single
    Get
        Return mBlend
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Single)
        mBlend = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    If mImg1 Is Nothing OrElse mImg2 Is Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor), New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))
    Else
        Dim rc As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
        Dim cm As ColorMatrix = New ColorMatrix()
        Dim ia As ImageAttributes = New ImageAttributes()
        cm.Matrix33 = mBlend
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImg2, rc, 0, 0, mImg2.Width, mImg2.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)
        cm.Matrix33 = 1.0F - mBlend
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImg1, rc, 0, 0, mImg1.Width, mImg1.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia)
    End If
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub

End Class
```

Then drag 'CustomPictureBox' and 'Timer' from Toolbox to the form.

Finally, you can refer to the following code to change the contents of a picture box every 3 seconds.

```
Private mBlend As Single
Private mDir As Integer = 1
Public index As Integer = 0
Public Images As List(Of Image) = New List(Of Image)()
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Images.Add(New Bitmap("path of picture1"))
    Images.Add(New Bitmap("path of picture2"))
    Images.Add(New Bitmap("path of picture3"))
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 60
    CustomPictureBox1.Image1 = Images(index)
    index += 1
    CustomPictureBox1.Image2 = Images(index)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    mBlend += mDir * 0.02F
    If mBlend > 1 Then
        mBlend = 0.0F
        If (index + 1) < Images.Count Then
            CustomPictureBox1.Image1 = Images(index)
            index += 1
            CustomPictureBox1.Image2 = Images(index)
        Else
            CustomPictureBox1.Image1 = Images(index)
            CustomPictureBox1.Image2 = Images(0)
            index = 0
        End If
    End If
    CustomPictureBox1.Blend = mBlend
End Sub
```

Result of my test.

[image]