# transition between images for picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transition of images in Windows Forms Picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270919/transition-of-images-in-windows-forms-picture-box)

I use the code below to change images in a picturebox every 5 seconds, but it's not looking good when changing an image: I want a transition effect between images.

### Used Code

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap[] pictures = new Bitmap[9];
        pictures[0] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\cf3.jpg");
        pictures[1] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\cf4.jpg");
        pictures[2] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l1.JPG");
        pictures[3] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l2.JPG");
        pictures[4] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l3.JPG");
        pictures[5] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l4.JPG");
        pictures[6] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l5.JPG");
        pictures[7] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l6.JPG");
        pictures[8] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l7.JPG");

        Random random = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            int attempt = random.Next(0, pictures.Length);
            pictureBox1.Image = pictures[attempt];
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

example code greatly appreciated thanks in advance...

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it; you should use a `Timer`.

Comment: @Slaks can you give me sample code please...

Comment: @SwDevMan81 but i am getting that code ....

Comment: @bemused can you tell me in brief .. i am new to c#...

Comment: See Han's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270919/transition-of-images-in-windows-forms-picture-box/3271808#3271808) in the duplicate question and you'll get your code... He even uses a Timer as SLaks suggests

Comment: The thread, the background worker thread, different from the main UI thread, can be used to set the picturebox? _but its not looking good_ means a exception occurred?

Comment: @jwJung no its working correct but i want transition effect between images (i mean sudden image change looks not good to see)

Comment: I don't think you're really going to get a transition with a .NET Picture box.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 thanks Dev at last i get it by your help only and i posted below for others help...

Comment: You are new to C#, if I were you I would go with WPF/Silverlight, NOT WinForms. It's old and will not be supported in the future. WPF is much more modern and such effects, among with lots of other visually appealing features (as Microsoft learned that user experience IS something important), which are easy to use. My suggestion is to move to WPF if this is the beginning. Even though you may get the desired result, it will be much more complicated and probably more "hacky"

Comment: @can: WinForms **will** be supported in the future.

Comment: @SLaks: sure, for some more time. but it is an old technology, and there's no point for adopting something old rather than something new and more visually appealing (especially for an example like this one). i didn't mean that we won't be seeing winform apps. sure we will, but the motivation is obviously towards wpf/sl, not winforms. it will of course stay, but for backwards compatibility. i see no point microsoft investing any more in winforms, while there is wpf and sl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply take new code file and paste below code in it

an original answer for the similar question, answer taken from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519956/drawimage-with-opacity/5520096#5520096)

### Answer

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class BlendPanel : Panel
{
private Image mImg1;
private Image mImg2;
private float mBlend;
public BlendPanel()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
}
public Image Image1
{
    get { return mImg1; }
    set { mImg1 = value; Invalidate(); }
}
public Image Image2
{
    get { return mImg2; }
    set { mImg2 = value; Invalidate(); }
}
public float Blend
{
    get { return mBlend; }
    set { mBlend = value; Invalidate(); }
}
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (mImg1 == null || mImg2 == null)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    else
    {
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
        cm.Matrix33 = mBlend;
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImg2, rc, 0, 0, mImg2.Width, mImg2.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
        cm.Matrix33 = 1F - mBlend;
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mImg1, rc, 0, 0, mImg1.Width, mImg1.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
}
```

Build your project.  You can now drop a BlendPanel from the top of the toolbox onto your form.  Here's a sample program that uses it:

```
    private float mBlend;
    private int mDir = 1;
    public int count = 0;
    public Bitmap[] pictures;

    public void myPhoto()
    {
        pictures = new Bitmap[9];
        pictures[0] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\cf3.jpg");
        pictures[1] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\cf4.jpg");
        pictures[2] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l1.JPG");
        pictures[3] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l2.JPG");
        pictures[4] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l3.JPG");
        pictures[5] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l4.JPG");
        pictures[6] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l5.JPG");
        pictures[7] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l6.JPG");
        pictures[8] = new Bitmap(@"Library Images\l7.JPG");

        timer1.Interval = 50; //time of transition
        timer1.Tick += BlendTick;
        try
        {
            blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
            blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void BlendTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mBlend += mDir * 0.02F;
        if (mBlend > 1)
        {
            mBlend = 0.0F;
            if ((count + 1) < pictures.Length)
            {
                blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
            }
            else
            {
                blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[0];
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        blendPanel1.Blend = mBlend;
    }
```

You'll need to modify the `new Bitmap(@"yourimagePath");` calls.  Build and run.  You should see the displayed image smoothly morph from your first image to your second image without any flickering.

I hope it helps for other...

Comment: Plagiarized from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520096/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant I wanted to reference your answer but didn't find at that time, I just wanted to add only second part of my answer. anyway I added your answer as a reference