# Image transition effect between images

Tags: c#, winforms

i read this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6712572/728750

and implement the code in my application but the problem is image is changing so fast because `timer1.Interval = 50` when i increase timer Interval to 300 then i found transition effect is not looking good.

so see my code and give me suggestion that what i need to change in code as a result transition between two images should look fine and smooth but i will be able to set any interval value for my main timer.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BlendSlideShow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private float mBlend;
        private int mDir = 1;
        public int count = 0;
        public Bitmap[] pictures;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictures = new Bitmap[9];
            pictures[0] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img1.jpg");
            pictures[1] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img2.jpg");
            pictures[2] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img3.jpg");
            pictures[3] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img4.jpg");
            pictures[4] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img5.jpg");
            pictures[5] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img6.jpg");
            pictures[6] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img7.jpg");
            pictures[7] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img8.jpg");
            pictures[8] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img9.jpg");

            timer1.Interval = 50; //time of transition
            timer1.Tick += BlendTick;
            try
            {
                blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private string GetImgFolderPath()
        {
            string _Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\..\..\images\";
            return _Path;
        }

        private void BlendTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mBlend += mDir * 0.02F;
            if (mBlend > 1)
            {
                mBlend = 0.0F;
                if ((count + 1) < pictures.Length)
                {
                    blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                    blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
                }
                else
                {
                    blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                    blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[0];
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            blendPanel1.Blend = mBlend;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a) there are quite a few values between 50 and 300, right? Playing music with only two sets of speed would also fail..  - b) Maybe studying [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563782/how-to-fade-in-and-fade-out-fading-transition-image-on-panelbackgroud-image/28565675#28565675) could help.

Comment: Best usage of try-catch ever!

Comment: BTW: I've got awesome results from using the tiny [DotNet Transitions](https://github.com/UweKeim/dot-net-transitions) library.

Comment: Damn, that's my code.  You need another timer that delays between the transitions so the user can look at the image for a while.

Comment: i never claim that code written by rather at top i mention url from where i got the code.

Comment: would u show how to add another timer to delay the image transition please sir.

Comment: @HansPassant without second timer i sorted the problem. full code give here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

my full code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BlendSlideShow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private float mBlend;
        private int mDir = 1;
        public int count = 0;
        public Bitmap[] pictures;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictures = new Bitmap[9];
            pictures[0] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img1.jpg");
            pictures[1] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img2.jpg");
            pictures[2] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img3.jpg");
            pictures[3] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img4.jpg");
            pictures[4] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img5.jpg");
            pictures[5] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img6.jpg");
            pictures[6] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img7.jpg");
            pictures[7] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img8.jpg");
            pictures[8] = new Bitmap(GetImgFolderPath() + "img9.jpg");

            timer1.Interval = 50; //time of transition
            timer1.Tick += BlendTick;
            try
            {
                blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private string GetImgFolderPath()
        {
            string _Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\..\..\images\";
            return _Path;
        }

        int numberOfTicks;
        int ticksBeforeBlendStarts = 100;

        private void BlendTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numberOfTicks >= ticksBeforeBlendStarts)
            {
                mBlend += mDir * 0.02F;
                if (mBlend > 1)
                {
                    mBlend = 0.0F;
                    if ((count + 1) < pictures.Length)
                    {
                        blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                        blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[++count];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        blendPanel1.Image1 = pictures[count];
                        blendPanel1.Image2 = pictures[0];
                        count = 0;
                    }

                    numberOfTicks = 0;
                }
                blendPanel1.Blend = mBlend;
            }
            numberOfTicks++;
        }
    }
}
```